# Was Manny abducted by Patrick's brother?

Tags: revivalist

In *[Working Stiff](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/9640024-working-stiff)*, first book of the *Revivalist* series, which deals with a nanite treatment that can revive the dead and the struggle over how the treatment will be used, two things are established:

- Side character Manny owes a life debt to corporate agent Patrick McCallister due to Patrick having rescued him from being buried in a coffin underground by a serial killer (which was the result of the killer realizing that Manny, then a profiler at the FBI, was onto him).
- Patrick's older brother was a sociopath who'd progressed to the level of being a serial killer at the time of his death at Patrick's hands to save a female victim.

Patrick, at the time he found Manny, doesn't seem to be any form of law enforcement, just "consulting" for them, so it seems odd that he'd be involved in a search for a missing agent. Which then led to the question, in my mind, as to whether he knew about Manny because, in the immediate aftermath of shooting his brother, he found evidence that Manny had been buried, and where.

There are apparently two more books in the series, which I'm attempting to source now, but I figured I'd ask on the off chance someone else already knew the answer.